# Is there a way to create custom style for underline in text?

Tags: flutter

I want to create custom styled underline as shown below. I can see some inbuilt test decoration styles (bold, dotted, double and wavy), wanted something like below. Is there a way we can achieve this styling in flutter ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the world of Flutter where you compose different widget trees in order to get your desired result.

**Result**:

[image]

**Code**

```dart
IntrinsicWidth(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(
            "Expenses",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 5,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 3,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 5,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 8,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```